# PHP concatenate &para to variable

Tags: php, html

I need to concatenate `&para` with some variable to create a url, but `&para` prints as ¶.

How can I use `&para` as string in PHP.

```
$url = $req . "&param=" . $param;
```

But instead of `&param=` I am getting `¶m=`

Comment: how are you using $url?

Comment: just look at the plain output of the browser (View source code), everything should be finde. Problem is That &para is interpreted as an entity, even if the semicolon is missing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100905/para-turns-into-within-pre

Comment: I am using the url as  `echo file_get_contents($url); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&` so it should look like `&amp;param=`